# Bootstrap 4 column not centering

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to center the 2 rows in the page but aligned to the left of the container.
This is the code I use:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center menufoot">
        <div class="col centeredcol">
            <div class="row menurow">
                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">Quienes Somos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Nuestra Historia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Nuestros Valores</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cifras Clave</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- end col -->
                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">Actividades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Químicos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Granulados y Pulverulentos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Transporte y Logística de Vehículos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Estocaje de Vehículos: Campas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Multimodal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Servicios Asociados al Transporte</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- end col -->
                <div class="col-sm-auto">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">Clientes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div><!-- end col -->
            </div><!--End menurow -->
            <div class="row copyrow">
                <div class="col">
                    &copy; Copyright <a href="#">Copyright</a> 2018 | <a href="#">Aviso Legal</a> | <a href="#">Política de Cookies</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Copyrow -->
        </div><!-- End centeredcol -->
    </div><!-- end menufoot -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

When I take out the centeredcol it centers both rows individually which is not the result i'm looking for.

Comment: Just a tip. U might upload your code as a snippet so others can run/test your code.

Comment: justify-content-center   add this class to menurow and copyrow and give a try

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally changing centeredcol to col-mx-auto did the trick.